# jquery selectmenu code issue

Tags: jquery-ui

i have this code http://pastie.org/1431114 what is wrong with it? i only get the regions select list when i click a country select for a second time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using

```
$('select#country').selectmenu({
    select: function(event, options) {
```

and

```
 <select id="country" name="country" 
            onchange="javascript: get_regions(this.value)">
```

Probably it will be much easier if you will use code like this

```
$('select#country').change(function(){
   var value = $(this).val();
   //ajax call
})
```